# Three js raycaster not working for gltf model

Tags: three.js

I add a gltf format model to scene, and it shows. when i try to get intersects by

```
raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children )
```

its not working

it worked on obj format model

Comment: solved, use raycaster.intersectObjects( model.children, true )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raycasting against 'subscenes' in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607435/raycasting-against-subscenes-in-three-js)