# can three.js raycaster interset with the Group model exported by fbx2gltf?

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting, gltf

Help bro. I use three.js raycaster() function to intersect a Object3D in the Group, but it return nothing....and the raycaster() can intersect with the THREE.mesh if I put a mesh into the scene, SO Does it means that the raycaster() function  can't support the import Object?

> code to intersect on the click event

```
        function onMouseClick(event) {
            mouse.x = ((event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left) / canvas.offsetWidth) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - ((event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top) / canvas.offsetHeight) * 2 + 1;

            raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

            var clickobjstore = raycaster.intersectObjects(huojia.children[0], true);

            console.log(clickobjstore);

            for (var i = 0; i < clickobjstore.length; i++) {
                console.log(clickobjstore);
                clickobjstore[i].object.material.color.set(0xff0000);

            }
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
```

> img of the group object on console

[the group object on the memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e16ES.png)

Comment: its solved and so on

Comment: Recursive raycasting will work on the nested objects yes. If you've solved this then feel free to post an answer to your question so others can use it. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raycasting against 'subscenes' in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607435/raycasting-against-subscenes-in-three-js)